# Pgfplots on function composition problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm a rookie to `pgfplots`.

Here is the code that I want to plot the function `$\sin(2x-5/3)$`.

The problem is that the plot of `$c(a(x))$` doesn't work. I have tried different combinations of composed functions but all the same. Besides, the plots are straightlines.

[image: THE RECOMPILED RESULT]

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2*x-5/3)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{c}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(x))}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines = middle,
                    xmin=-10,
                    xmax=10,
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
                    width = 0.8\textwidth,
                    height = 0.8\textwidth,
                    xlabel = {$x$},
                    ylabel = {$f(x)$},]
                    \addplot[
                    samples=200, 
                    smooth,
                    color=blue,
                    ]{c(x)};
                    \addplot[
                    samples=200, 
                    smooth,
                    color=red,
                    ]{c(a(x))};
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. The `pgf` trig functions assume degrees as input, try using `sin(rad(x))`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Well thank you! But I think it's sth wrong with my code, because other composition functions cannot be printed well, too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot, it should of course be `sin(deg(x))`. There is one other mistake though, I'll write an answer.

Comment: There is another alternative: you could use [`tikzplotlib`](https://pypi.org/project/tikzplotlib/) package (with python) and convert matplotlib plots into PGFPlots (PGF/TikZ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the `pgf` trig functions assume degrees as input, I guess you intended radians. Hence, you need to convert the input to `sin` to degrees, e.g. with `sin(deg(x))`.

Second, when using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, the input to the function is not represented by `x` in the function definition, but by `#1` for the first argument, `#2` for the second (if you have one), etc.

This means that your functions need to be declared like this:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{2*#1-5/3}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{c}{1}{\pgfmathparse{sin(deg(#1))}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{2*#1-5/3}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{c}{1}{\pgfmathparse{sin(deg(#1))}}

% alternative method for declaring functions
%\tikzset{
%  declare function={
%    a(\x) = 2*\x - 5/3;
%    c(\x) = sin(deg(\x));
%  }
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        every axis x label/.style={
           at={(current axis.right of origin)},
           anchor=west
        },
        width = 0.8\textwidth,
        height = 0.8\textwidth,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$f(x)$}
        ]
        
        \addplot[
           samples=200, 
           smooth,
           color=blue,
           ] {c(x)};
        
        \addplot[
           samples=200, 
           smooth,
           color=red,
           ] {c(a(x))};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great help! Thanks a lot.